# How to store a file in Java, which is generated on execution of a .exe file?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a .exe file, which produces certain files when made to run :
[image: The window appearing after executing the .exe file]

The files produced are *WatchDataTest, ngrtgs.test, shubhangi, slatey (as they appear in the image)*

I want to run the .exe file through a separate Java Program and obtain reference to the above files. How can this be done?

**My point of view**: I think, obtaining an OutputStream(wrapped by ObjectOutputStream) on the Process object of this executable can be used to read the objects (files, in this case). However, I am not sure in what way does this executable provides reference to the files produced. Other than that, I have a confusion whether the GUI display is part of the output. I mean does the OutputStream of this executable include the GUI object, which displays on the screen? If not, what all is the output of this .exe?(Pretty confusion here)

Comment: can you run these exe using command promt and let check the behaviour there same thing can be done using processbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .exe file calls your OS native functions to create those files. You cannot catch that from Java.

If you want to *read the content* of those files from Java, find them in the directory structure, and open them for reading with the normal Java File I/O API.

I think you want to access those certificates, right? Most likely they're not stored in separate files, but in one file called *keystore*. In this case I recommend to use `Java PKI` API or tools to manage your keystore.